# How to loop a php file when there is a $_GET?

Tags: php

I am a little confused on the structure that i need to build this php file.

I have a `$_SESSION['Listingname'] = $_GET['Listingname'];` at the start of the file, to get a listingname from the last php file. But i also want to have a button that submit some text and refresh the page. Not sure how i should approach it, because if i refresh/reload the page, then it can't perform `$_GET['Listingname']` then it gives an error of undefined method.

Some advice would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: try to put your code here.

Comment: Use this .. `$_SESSION['Listingname'] = isset($_GET['Listingname'])?$_GET['Listingname']:'Not Set';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
if(!empty($_GET['Listingname'])) {
    $_SESSION['Listingname'] = $_GET['Listingname'];
}
```

Comment: If you are doing an `!empty` check , then `isset` is not necessary. :)

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran.. :)

Answer (score 1):

try check empty

```
if(!empty($_GET['Listingname'])) {
    $_SESSION['Listingname'] = $_GET['Listingname'];
}
```

or try to set in hidden field value of `$_SESSION['Listingname']` and send it to again with submit if you want reuse it